# CSS Absolute Positioned List Size

Tags: jquery, css, list

So I have a List and cannot figure how to change it's content's display format so that the width and height of the UL auto-sizes the to LI content.

I have updated the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/devin85/tMYxT/7](http://jsfiddle.net/devin85/tMYxT/7) ...

Hovering the level 2 items will illustrate my problem-
 "Bus Stops"
 "Employees"
 "Fences"
 "Vehicles"

Thanks for the assistance.

Devin

Comment: Please post your problem code as well as the jsfiddle line (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle)

Comment: The problem is a CSS one. When you hover the 2nd level of menu items, they reveal a 3rd level. As you can see however, these items are not displaying within their <ul> container, as the <ul> is not sizing to the requirements of its contained <li>'s ... If there is anything else I can provide, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you limit the sub-menu height to 32px;
fix in css (line:32):

```
#navigation .submenu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 32px;
left: 0px;
background-color: transparent; 
white-space: nowrap;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Billy corrected this to height auto, but not on ".submenu", but rather on ".submenu .submenu", to target level 3. This however doesnt explain why the 4th menu item's width seems crushed. Thanks for giving it a go though!

Comment: add **width:auto** as well it gets width from container <li>

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Something seems to be impeding the last area.

Comment: The white-space: no-wrap in combination with width:auto was exactly what was needed! Perfect! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the end of your css code:

```
#navigation .submenu .submenu { height:auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks Billy. Your height:auto did the trick to the height, however as you can see the 4th menu item still seems to be crushed in width by something. Do you know why?